# WD Green Hard Drive and home linux server

Tags: linux, hard-drive, kernel

Are newer WD Green Hard Drives still a problem for Linux nowadays? The discussion here is focused on home linux servers, not NAS or data centers.

Here is a summary of my research from googling.

- ["These drives have a serious problem when used with Linux"](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=73573), which was fully discussed in late 2009. Given that is over 6 years ago, I think we should take the solutions there with some precaution.
- [Linux and the old Western Digital Green Caviar drives don’t play well with each other](https://community.wd.com/t/green-caviar-high-load-cycle-cout-after-short-operation-time/13283), which was discussed in May 2010.
- The latest discussion I can find is [Stop Western Digital Green HDD Dying On Linux](http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/western-digital-green-hdd-how-to-stop-them-dying-on-you.4814), which was posted quite recently, 13 January 2015. However, the discussion is still about 500GB, or 1TB Green drives, which were the focus of above discussion 6 years ago.
- I believe the most accurate discussion and solution should be the [advisory published by Western Digital](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=5357). Since it provides solution for Linux users, I believe this should the official answer.

However, the problem is,

- there is no publish date of that [advisory](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=5357).
- there is only a small number of WD disks listed in that advisory. Does it mean that all that are not listed, e.g. the WD Green 4 TB Desktop Hard Drive with Model Number WD40EZRX-RTL have no problems now?
- the problem is that there is no update info of that advisory, so I really am not sure whether the problem still holds for current Linux or not.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the issue is that the "green" drives save energy (and wear) by frequently shutting down (going to sleep). This is not optimal for a server. See http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=97626

Comment: Not really. The link you posted is about *"Green Drive goes in to sleep mode after not being used for **15 minutes**"*, which is caused by windows Power settings in the Control Panel. In Linux, it is a different issue. Read the materials I posted. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have personal experience with WD Green drives on Linux, exactly because of this issue. (I use WD Reds in my home server.) However, I was able to find significantly more recent sources that indicate that it is still a problem with all WD Green drives, even the new ones:

- [November 2014 - WD##EZRX-series](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Western_Digital_Green_-_Drive_Fix_-_Linux)
- [January 2015 - unknown series, purchased in late 2014](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/2s9qqb/psa_stop_western_digital_green_hdd_dying_on_linux/cnnhkxv) (compare the black and green bought within two months of each other in that post)

Comment: OK, I think I can accept that as an answer, because at the end of your first quoted wiki, it says *"That's it! All done. You can now enjoy the reliability and speed from the WD Green drive that you expected to have when you bought it."*